# Difference between @android:style/android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar and @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

I am seeing a strange issue.
In my manifest if I declare a theme for my activity as below:

```
<activity
            android:name="test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</activity>
```

I dont receive any warning and it works fine. But if I change the theme to :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Note: removed the extra "android:" after style/.

Now I get a warning saying Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar requires API level 14.

Whats the difference in the 2 ways of declaring the theme?

Comment: `android:style/android:...` is incorrect.

Comment: It does work, with no warnings, that caused a confusion